# Submit useragent information with Freeform or similiar

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms, solspace

I am maintaining an ecommerce site running with EE and CT. We have a Freeform Form set up on the Contact page. A lot of incoming emails from that form center around technical problems, e.g.. people not able to checkout for whatever reason.

To nail the problems down and to be able to better reproduce the problems I'd would ideally have the user-agent info at hand directly. I am thinking about (probably secretly) submitting this whenever a user fills out the Freeform form so I don't have to ask the people and send emails back and forth (it's tedious and to be honest most people having problems are the not so tech-savvy so telling them where to find the information needed isn't easy and most of the time results are never returned or are incomplete, like "I'm using Firefox on Windows").

I am totally open on what to use here. This means I don't necessarily have to use Freeform although it's pretty nice. I'd probably even upgrade to Freeform Pro for this but couldn't find any valuable information on the website regarding this.

Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a hidden field (create a new text field in the CP and on the front end just use a hidden field in its place so it records) and inject the UA via JS from the onsubmit param of the form:

```
{exp:freeform:form form_name="my_form" form:onsubmit="document.getElementById('ua').value=window.navigator.userAgent;"}

<input type="hidden" name="ua" id="ua" value="" />

//rest form stuff
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works beautifully. Couldn't get to it earlier, thus the late feedback.